# Can you access the object representation of any object through a char*?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

I have stumbled upon a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/c7btvz/how_can_one_implement_memcpy_in_standard_c/) in which a user has found an interesting detail of the C++ standard. The thread has not spawned much constructive discussion, therefore I will retell my understanding of the problem here:

- OP wants to reimplement `memcpy` in a standard-compliant way
- They attempt to do so by using `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&foo)`, which is an allowed exception to the strict aliasing restrictions, in which reinterpreting as `char` is allowed to access the "object representation" of an object.
- [[expr.reinterpret.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.reinterpret.cast-7) says that doing so results in `static_­cast<cv T*>(static_­cast<cv void*>(v))`, so `reinterpret_cast` in this case is equivalent to static_cast'ing first to `void *` and then to `char *`.
- [[expr.static.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#13) in combination with [[basic.compound]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4)

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 void” **can be converted** to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 T”, where T is an object type and cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. [...] **if the original pointer value points to an object a, and there is an object b of type T (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible with a, the result is a pointer to b. [...]** [emphasis mine]

Consider now the following union class:

```
union Foo{
    char c;
    int i;
};
// the OP has used union, but iiuc,
// it can also be a struct for the problem to arise.
```

OP has thus come to the conclusion that reinterpreting a `Foo*` as `char*` in this case yields a pointer pointing to the first char member of the union (or its object representation), rather than to the object representation of the union itself, i.e. it points *only to the member*. While this appears superficially to be the same, and corresponds to the same memory address, the standard seems to differentiate between the "value" of a pointer and its corresponding address, in that on the abstract C++ machine, a pointer belongs to a certain object only. Incrementing it beyond that object (compare with end() of an array) is undefined behavior.

OP thus argues that if the standard forces the `char*` to be associated with the objects's first member instead of the object representation of the whole union object, dereferencing it after one incrementation is UB, which allows a compiler to optimize as if it were impossible for the resultant `char*` to ever access the following bytes of the int member. This implies that it is not possible to legally access the complete object representation of a class object which is pointer-interconvertible with a `char` member.

The same would, if I understand correctly apply if "union" was simply replaced with "struct", but I have taken this example from the original thread.

What do you think? Is this a standard defect? Is it a misinterpretation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220949/discussion-on-question-by-jmc-possible-standard-defect-disallowing-access-to-obj).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This video](https://youtu.be/_qzMpk-22cc?t=2647), linked in the comments (now chat) by @KonradRudolph is likely the answer to the problem.

At around the 40min mark, Timur Doumler, who is a member of the ISO C++ commitee, discusses the possibility of accessing byte representations. The summary is that any attempt of accessing byte representation except `memcpy` is UB. The situation in the OP does not even arise without making use of UB because the very act of using a pointer to an object like an array, or doing any pointer arithmetic on it is UB, as these operations are only well-defined when dealing with actual array objects, as far as the abstract machine is concerned.

Also, while reinterpreting a pointer as a `char*` does not on its own violate aliasing rules, there is technically no guarantee that the resulting `char*` will point to the first byte of the object.

The only legal way of accessing byte representations is to `memcpy` the object into a char array. This means that reimplementing `memcpy` is impossible.

Timur Doumler additionally describes this as a wording defect that will hopefully be fixed in C++23 and presents a paper that proposes a fix to this.

Comment: Note that the paper in question is [P1839](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1839r2.pdf). It has been [approved by EWG *specifically* as a DR](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/592).